# Unable to debug another assembly's code

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I have a WCF project that I am running in Visual Studio 2010, and it is referencing another project's implementation.

When I set a breakpoints inside the other project, and press F5 to load up the test client, I'm  unable to hit any breakpoints in the other assemblies, only the ones in my test client project.

I even checked the bin folder, and the dll and pdb files are there.

How come the symbols are loaded for the other assembly?

Comment: Make sure you're referencing the project itself, not not its compiled assembly.

Comment: Yeah I'm referencing it.

Comment: In order for me to debug, I had to add in code: System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() / .Launch() in order to debug. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

You need to attach your debugger to the WCF host. It is either IIS or self host executable.

Answer (score 0):

Look out for...

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
```

... in svcutil generateed WCF code. It will stop you debugging this code.

Answer (score 0):

See if my blog post on this issue helps

http://w4ik.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/debugging-a-wcf-service/

the main point is that you may need to modify the client's config file like so

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" />
<system.web>
```